# How to get axios to get data from SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a page that is supposed to display SharePoint list data.  I was able to get it to work using REST API but since I'm using VUE.js framework, I wanted to try axios.  I don't get an error when I look in the console but I do see a bunch of xml data instead of json.  What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>                      
</tr>
<tr v-for="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.Title }}</td>
    <td>{{user.First_x0020_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.Last_x0020_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{ user.Phone }}</td>                       
</tr>
</table>
{{fieldNames}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        fieldNames: "HELLO SharePoint 2013",
        status: '',
        users: []           
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getListData();
    },
    methods: {
        getListData: function(){
         var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('siteAdmins')/items";
        /*var headers = { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
        };*/
            this.status = "getting data...";
            var vm = this;
            axios.get(endPointUrl).then(response => {
               console.log(response.data);

               vm.users = response.data

               /*for (var i = 0; i < response.data.value.length; i++) {
                        vm.users.push({
                          title: String(response.data.value[i]["Title"]),
                          fName: response.data.value[i]["First_x0020_Name"] != null ? String(response.data.value[i]["First_x0020_Name"]) : "",
                          lName: response.data.value[i]["Last_x0020_Name"] != null ? String(response.data.value[i]["Last_x0020_Name"]) : "",
                          phone: response.data.value[i]["Phone"] != null ? String(response.data.value[i]["Phone"])                                                    
                     });
                     console.log(resonse.data.value[i].Title);
                }*/
             });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's an image of what I see in the console.
[image]

Comment: looks like your accept header is commented out...

Answer (score 1):

Replace `"response.data"` with `"response.data.value"`

SharePoint likes to wrap all of its responses in another variable.

The final code should look like this

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>                      
</tr>
<tr v-for="user in users">
    <td>{{ user.Title }}</td>
    <td>{{user.First_x0020_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.Last_x0020_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{ user.Phone }}</td>                       
</tr>
</table>
{{fieldNames}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        fieldNames: "HELLO SharePoint 2013",
        status: '',
        users: []           
    },
    created: function(){
        this.getListData();
    },
    methods: {
        getListData: function(){
         var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('siteAdmins')/items";
        var headers = { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" 
        };
            this.status = "getting data...";
            var vm = this;
            axios.get(endPointUrl).then(response => {
               console.log(response.data.value);
               vm.users = response.data.value
             });
        }
    }
});
```

I just tested this with the list name and field names matching the ones in my environment and it works just great

Comment: Hi Razvan, that solution doesn't work for me.  I'm not using vue but plain vanila javascript.  Does it matter?

Comment: What is the headers object doing? It doesn't appear to actually get used.